# How do I add and remove items from a list using Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to learn Knockout and I'm following these two tutorials:
[Tutorial 1](http://www.charlesnurse.com/Blog/Post/445/It-s-a-Knockout-7-Adding-items-to-and-Removing-items-from-Observable-Arrays)
[Better list example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html)

But after half a day of trying (and failing), I'm not able to add or remove an item.
[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/THJE3/4/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**To clarify**
Why doesn't `self.items.push()` add the new item to my list? Is it because of the `self.item_id` property?

My HTML is like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" data-bind="value: item_id" />
<input class="form-control" type="search" data-bind="value: item_name" />     
<button class="btn" data-bind="click: addItem, enable: item_name().length > 2">Add</button>

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">     
  // This list is retrieved from database on page load
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span id="123" data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}">Americanino</span>
    <span data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span>
  </li>      

  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span id="842" data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}">Diesel</span>
    <span data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span>
  </li>          
</ul>
```

And my JS looks like this:

```
function item(id, name){
    var self = this;
    self.item_id = ko.observable(id);
    self.item_name = ko.observable(name);    
    //test
    alert(self.item_id() + ' - ' + self.item_name());    
}

var manageListModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.item_id = ko.observable('345');
    self.item_name = ko.observable();

    self.addItem = function() {     
        if (self.item_name() != "") {      
            self.items.push(new item(self.item_id(),self.item_name()));
            self.item_name(""); 
        }
    }.bind(self); 

    // Remove item
    self.removeItem = function(item) {
        alert('tert');
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new manageListModel());
```

**UPDATE**

So after banging my head in the wall for a few hours, I finally found a solution that works pretty well. I hope this code will help other with similar problems :)

So what did I do?

- I created a template for the list item. If you have 10 items in your list and use `ko.observableArray()`, the template will consists of 10 items. So for every item you add, you will get 10 in the list.
- I cloned the existing list since `ko.observableArray()` removes any static content in the list
- Looped through my cloned list and put the value-data into an array which I passed into `ko.observableArray`

Here is my final code:
([You can see the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/THJE3/46/))

My HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" data-bind="value: item_id" />
<input class="form-control" type="search" data-bind="value: item_name" />     
<button class="btn" data-bind="click: addItem, enable: function(){item_name().length > 2}">Add</button>

<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'item-item-template', data: $root.items}">     
  // This list is retrieved from database on page load
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span id="123" data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}">Americanino</span>
    <span data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span>
  </li>      

  <li class="list-group-item">
    <span id="842" data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}">Diesel</span>
    <span data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span>
  </li>          
</ul> 

<script type="text/html" id="item-item-template">
<!--ko foreach: $data-->
    <li>
      <span id="" data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}"></span>
      <a href="#" class="remove el-icon-remove-circle" data-bind="click: $root.removeitem"></a>
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

The JS code

```
// List item
function brand(name, id) {
    var self = this;
    self.item_name = ko.observable(name);
    self.item_id = ko.observable(id);
}


// Create array of existing list
function create_list(exiting_list){
    var arr_list = [];

    $(exiting_list).find('li').each(function(e,li){
        var id = $(li).find('span').prop('id');
        var name = $(li).find('span').html();
        arr_list.push({
                 item_id: id,
                 item_name: name
             });
     });
    return arr_list;
}

// Manage list
// Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/THJE3/46/
var manageitemListModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    // Data
    var exiting_list = $('.item-list ul').clone();
    self.items = ko.observableArray(create_list(exiting_list));
    self.item_name = ko.observable('');
    self.item_id = ko.observable('');

    // Operations
    self.additem = function() {
        if (self.item_name() != "") {
            self.items.push(new item(self.item_name(),self.item_id()));
            self.item_name("");
        }
    }.bind(self);

    // Remove item
    self.removeitem = function(item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new manageitemListModel());
```

Comment: Please include what exactly isn't working, and why your solutions didn't work.

Comment: As I write in my question: `I'm not able to add or remove an item.`. And if I knew why it doesn't work, I would not have to ask help from you guys.

Comment: You have an issue with the `enable` binding. You are using `item_name().length`. The model has `undefined` for that property. Either change it to check for that state or give the item name a default empty string value. Then move the data for the two `li` into your viewmodel and put a single `li`. As it stands, you are duplicating elements per data object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on the following [version](http://jsfiddle.net/THJE3/22/)

Don't forget press F12 in your favorite browser, your binding was incorrect `item_name().length > 2`

- You can initialise `self.item_name = ko.observable("");`
- create additional computed property (*as for me this version is better*)

For instance

```
self.enableToAdd = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.item_name().length >2;
});

<button class="btn" data-bind="click: addItem, enable:enableToAdd">Add</button>
```

Here's more about [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Please note: if a binding has any error, all the binding doesn't work

Comment: Wadda you know. But not even Knouckouts own example uses `enable:function()`. So why is it working for them? Also, adding this function removes the existing items. The page will be loaded with X items.

Comment: Because it's initialized with empty string `ko.observable("")`

Comment: The initial data should be set in the model, not the html.

Comment: @Origineil But the list is retrieved from DB on page load. Does Knockout "force me" to load data through Ajax? GSserjo: I tried that in the start, but that too removed my list items on page load.

Comment: PHP, .Net, Java - it doesn't matter. The data is fetched server side on page load. Not client side through Ajax / Knockout.

Comment: @Steven no it doesn't force you, but you can load you data for instance on page loaded and you can write your own binding, some time it's really useful

Comment: I still don't understand how I can map my existing list and just add new items to this. I think I'm on to something here: http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/THJE3/17/ by adding `arrayMap` inside `observableArray`

Comment: I've updated your version, http://jsfiddle.net/THJE3/20/ added `loadData` method. Note your version has an error in this line `self.items`, invalid syntax, don't forget to press F12

Comment: Thanks. That will be usefull if I'm loading data through Ajax. Currently I'm loading data server side. Is there a way to keep existing list before Knockout removes it?

Comment: What do you mean "existing"? Do you mean data on the html? If so, you can call appropriate viewModel's method on the html

Comment: Yes - and how do I do that?

Comment: I've uppdated the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/THJE3/43/) and added some comments. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629652/knockoutjs-basic-model-architecture/23633191) you can find additional info about: JavaScript Module Pattern and Single page application

Comment: Hmm... I don't know how I can explain this more clearly so you can understand. But thanks for helping me a bit in the right direction :)

Comment: As I see you have some predefined static data and you want to display it without ajax call. Am I right?

Comment: When the web page is loaded, data is retrieved from Database. When the page is finished loading, it will have a nice list. Now the user can modify this list (this part is handled through JS / Knockout).

Comment: How do you create a "nice list"? How do u get data from DB? As I see all your samples have static li items, they are created by hand, not thru knockout. Any way if you want to use knockout you have to push your data to it

Answer (score 1):

Your "enable" function is requiring an object that is not defined by the time it's accessed. You need to verify if it exists before using its value. Here's a working version of the HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" value="" data-bind="value: item_id" />
    <input class="form-control" type="search" data-bind="value: item_name" />     

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn" data-bind="click: addItem, enable: item_name() ? item_name().length > 2 : false">Add</button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: items">

    <li class="list-group-item">
      <span data-bind="text: item_name, attr: {'id': item_id}"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem"></span>
    </li>      

  </ul>    

</div>
```